# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CalcOpticalFlowBM'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to get per block motion vectors between two frames. By using CalcOpticalFlowBM() as described in the official [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/legacy/doc/motion_analysis.html)

However it seems like the function has been removed to another package or something.

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? Here are the methods currently available: https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html

Comment: I am using the 4.2.0 version

Comment: It looks like `CalcOpticalFlowBM()` has not been available since at least 3.0.

Comment: So I either intstall an old version, or maybe there is another option to get per bloc motion vectors ?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d5/dc3/group__cudalegacy.html#ga6b4b2e196ebed9c3a4b6c6330e6e4306

It seems to have been moved to legacy using with CUDA.
You need to compile opencv to use it.